# WebRTC - peer2peer connection stopped working

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I started testing WebRTC and started with examples in https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/

I was testing this example:
https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/master/rtcpeerconnection/

I ran python's simple webserver: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Then tried out if that example works on my end. And it did. Then I modified one part of the code (`-` means removed line and `+` added line):

```
function start() {
  trace("Requesting local stream");
  startButton.disabled = true;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
  - navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream,
  + navigator.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}, gotStream,
    function(error) {
      trace("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
    });
}
```

When I ran it, video stopped working but I could hear my voice. Then I changed back how it was, but for some reason it stopped working all together.

Later I noticed that my camera was blocked for some reason, then I unblocked it, but it still does not work. I even replaced whole code with original one from github (even though it was the same).

And I get error without any error indication so I don't know whats wrong:

```
463.069: Requesting local stream main.js:31
465.550: navigator.getUserMedia error:
```

I also thought maybe somehow getUserMedia was disabled in Chromium (I use - Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972))

So I enabled `getUserMedia` in Chromium settings. But still nothing.

You can check how it is working on this link: http://www.simpl.info/rtcpeerconnection/

The line that points out error (31 line):

```
console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text);
```

Function that got this line:

```
var total = '';
function trace(text) {
  total += text;
  console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text);
}
```

Also whole javascript code:

```
var localStream, localPeerConnection, remotePeerConnection;

var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");

localVideo.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
trace("Local video currentSrc: " + this.currentSrc +
        ", videoWidth: " + this.videoWidth +
        "px,  videoHeight: " + this.videoHeight + "px");
});

remoteVideo.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
trace("Remote video currentSrc: " + this.currentSrc +
        ", videoWidth: " + this.videoWidth +
        "px,  videoHeight: " + this.videoHeight + "px");
});

var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var callButton = document.getElementById("callButton");
var hangupButton = document.getElementById("hangupButton");
startButton.disabled = false;
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;
startButton.onclick = start;
callButton.onclick = call;
hangupButton.onclick = hangup;

var total = '';
function trace(text) {
  total += text;
  console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text);
}

function gotStream(stream){
  trace("Received local stream");
  localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localStream = stream;
  callButton.disabled = false;
}

function start() {
  trace("Requesting local stream");
  startButton.disabled = true;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
  navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, gotStream,
    function(error) {
      trace("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
    });
}

function call() {
  callButton.disabled = true;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  trace("Starting call");

  if (localStream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
    trace('Using video device: ' + localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].label);
  }
  if (localStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
    trace('Using audio device: ' + localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].label);
  }

  var servers = null;

  localPeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace("Created local peer connection object localPeerConnection");
  localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotLocalIceCandidate;

  remotePeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace("Created remote peer connection object remotePeerConnection");
  remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotRemoteIceCandidate;
  remotePeerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

  localPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  trace("Added localStream to localPeerConnection");
  localPeerConnection.createOffer(gotLocalDescription);
}

function gotLocalDescription(description){
  localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
  trace("Offer from localPeerConnection: \n" + description.sdp);
  remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
  remotePeerConnection.createAnswer(gotRemoteDescription);
}

function gotRemoteDescription(description){
  remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
  trace("Answer from remotePeerConnection: \n" + description.sdp);
  localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description);
}

function hangup() {
  trace("Ending call");
  localPeerConnection.close();
  remotePeerConnection.close();
  localPeerConnection = null;
  remotePeerConnection = null;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  callButton.disabled = false;
}

function gotRemoteStream(event){
  remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  trace("Received remote stream");
}

function gotLocalIceCandidate(event){
  if (event.candidate) {
    remotePeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
    trace("Local ICE candidate: \n" + event.candidate.candidate);
  }
}

function gotRemoteIceCandidate(event){
  if (event.candidate) {
    localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
    trace("Remote ICE candidate: \n " + event.candidate.candidate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much trouble for such thing. I didn't notice that I was running same page on firefox when I was testing on chromium. So I'm guessing it got into a conflict. First unexpected thing happened when chromium blocked my camera and I didn't notice that.

Then I tried to run same program with firefox (version 30), but I guess its not turned on on firefox, because it didn't recognize some parameters from javascript file and threw some errors. Then I left that page hanging on firefox while my camera was running and even when I unblocked my camera on chromium I couldnt run it because of firefox.